# Can I set a log-in as an @before process in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Using IntelliJ to run Selenium tests using Chrome/Chromedriver.

There's a page I want to test but it is after the login screen ("localhost:port/dashboard"). When I set the driver to get that page the program stops at the login screen ("localhost:port/login") and does not navigate to the main page which has most of the elements I want to test. When learning Selenium I was navigating to either files held locally (so I just needed a folder path) or website front pages (like www.google.com).

Is there some way to just log-in as a "Before" condition or is there something I'm totally missing that makes doing this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I think doing login in before method for all the test would not be good. because there may be the cases where you don't require to do the login.

So better to create one method where implement the login functionality and call the same where you require login into the system.

e.g.

```
public void doLogin(String username, String password){

    driver.navigate().to("https://www.siteurl.com/login");
    driver.findElement(By.locator).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.locator).sendKeys(password);
    ....

    // click login button
}
```

And call this method where you require login.

```
@Test
public void verifyDetailsOnDashboard(){

    doLogin(username, password);
    ....

    // perform rest of functionality here   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Something like this was what I had in my head but couldn't get out. Now I'm getting a NullPointerException error so I need to figure out how to debug that so I can get to the elements I want to identify.